# open drive picker with a known fileId selected

Tags: google-picker

In my webapp it can happen that a user imported an owned drive file through a copy-pasted link. At that point I already know the fileId from the link, but I need to ask the user to go through the picker in order to make that file available within the app (I'm using drive.file scope only).

I tried using the View.setQuery(string) api, but I'm not sure it can help.

Is it possible to set a query for a specific fileId? Is there some other way to achieve it?

Comment: How do you get the ID?

Comment: the user gives it to me through copy-pasting of a drive.com url of the form `"https://drive.google.com/file/d/" + ID` (or the analog google docs url format, both contain the file ID)

Comment: Then is there a reason to not simply allow them to select the file using the picker from the start? It's easier than copying the ID from a URL...

Comment: the platform my company is developing allows the import of any file/link/gdrive, so in the upload form we also have a textarea for urls.
If a user pastes a gdrive url, it could also be a public gdrive file (no way to open that with the picker).
But in case it's private, we need to ask him for permission to open that specific file.

Comment: by the way, it looks like there's no existing way to do that today. I had also opened a feature request in the picker issuetracker and it just got approved. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187107726

Comment: Why don't you add the Drive Picker on the form instead of a text field? This will grant the permissions necessary.

Comment: As already explained, i need both. My app is not google-centric.
I think I can close the question, since the real answer is that what I'm asking is not possible right now and I need to wait for the google-picker team to implement it.